# What is the ideal load node for a cassandra node?

Tags: cassandra

I'm amidst preparing a **cassandra** **cluster** and i need to set thresholds or benchmarks for load on a cassandra node. What I need is **ideal** size,cost,load,etc parameters which ensure the nodes are **healthy**.

***Request you all out there to please help me with this!!!***

Comment: It depends. Hardware, workload, schema, network topology, backup strategy, repairs all can impact it, there is no single answer... its safe to say that 100% (1.0 load per core, so like 4.0 on a quad core) is the most efficient usage of hardware but with spikey load thats bad.

Comment: This is really highly speculative number, but usually the performance in the cluster should be something on the lines of 3-5 000 req/s per node depending on the actual workload. The writes are CPU bound, so more cores, the faster it can go. If the load is more read oriented then you will want to have more RAM, again this is really a speculative answer and to give more details please provide some info on your workload.

Comment: @MarkoŠvaljek and chris thanks for your reply. what i'm setting up is 4 node cluster in one DC on aws. According to requirement i'll add another DC, when i see a gradual increase in workload. currrent read write request count is 900 requests/sec